# mongoexport with regex query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to export from a mongo database using the following mongoexport command to search out text emoticons :

```
mongoexport -d <db> -c <col> -f text -q '{text: /.*:\)/}'
```

But when I try to execute the command mongoexport returns:

> assertion: 10340 Failure parsing JSON string near: text: /.*:

I have tried to use the hex escape for the right paren:

```
mongoexport -d <db> -c <col> -f text -q '{text: /.*:\x29/}'
```

but I get the same error at the same location. It appears the mongoexport parser halts when it encounters '\'. I have a difficulty believing that mongoexport has this limitation (since it makes using regular expressions nearly impossible), so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I ask why you are trying to escape the right paren?  I tried your query without the escape before the right paren and it worked : `'{text: /.*:)/}'`

As an alternative, if you need the escape in the query then you have to escape the escape symbol, since the string is getting parsed twice (the shell, then the database) : `'{text: /.*:\\)/}'`

Comment: when working on the query in the mongo command shell the parenthesis must be escaped or else you get a "Thu Oct 25 10:29:26 SyntaxError: unmatched ) in regular expression (shell):1" error. This happens whether or not I use $regex

Comment: But you are exactly right. The escape is not needed for the expression to be parsed. But now I am not exporting any records--which is likely an issue with my db or collection description.

Comment: Well, it isn't an issue with db or collection. A simple regex --'text: /.*your.*/'--finds and exports records but a regex with the right paren--'text: /.*:).*/'--generates no records. From a mongo shell query I know that there are over 700 documents with that particular pattern so something else is  going wrong

Comment: What happens if you run a query with the regex in the shell?

Comment: Again no records. mongoexport -d <db> -c <collection> -f text -q '{text: {$regex: /.*:).*/}}' exports 0 records.

Comment: A workaround is to just do the query--var cursor = db.<collection>.find({"text": /.*:\)+.*|:\-\)+.*|:=\)+.*|:D.*|.*:-\)+.*|.*=\)|\^_\^/}) and pipe it to a file.

Comment: That did it? Of course the double escape gets the forward slash through the mongoexport parser into the javascript parser. You rock!!